# adding new values to a vector based on condition (for and ifelse)

Tags: r

I need to create a vector(lets call it "support vector") that matches position in other vector ("main vector") with desired value. My guess is that the easiest way is to use `for` and `ifelse`. I am familiar with appending new values to a vector using `for` but it does not work with `ifelse`. Here is simple example that shows what I have in mind (please read # description):

```
#the "main vector" with fixed values
main_vector=c("ABC","ABC","ABC","XYZ")
#empty "support vector" which I want fill 
support_vector=c()
#loop that puts into "support vector" 1 if "ABC" and 0 if "XYZ"
for(i in 1:length(main_vector)){ifelse(main_vector[i]=="ABC",support_vector[i]=1,support_vector[i]=0}
```

It generates error that suggest `=` is an issue in my code (or am I wrong?). What method/functions should I use to bypass using `=`?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `ifelse` is vectorized. No need for loop.

Comment: no for loop necessary: `support_vector <- ifelse(main_vector == "ABC", 1, 0)`

Comment: You don't even need `ifelse`...just `as.integer(main_vector == 'ABC')`

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way could be:

```
support_vector <- as.numeric(main_vector == "ABC")
> support_vector
#[1] 1 1 1 0
```

For some reason if `OP` still want to use `for-loop` then there is no need of `ifelse` rather `if-else` can be more convenient/readable option for argument of length `1`.

```
support_vector <- c()
for(i in 1:length(main_vector)){
      if(main_vector[i]=="ABC"){
        support_vector[i]=1
      } else {
        support_vector[i]=0
      }
}
```

Note: Solution provided by @gdkrmr is very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach (not as nice as @gdkm or @MKR but may be useful in some way):

```
> main_vector=c("ABC","ABC","ABC","XYZ")
> support_vector <- sapply(main_vector, function(x) as.integer(x=="ABC"))
> support_vector
ABC ABC ABC XYZ 
  1   1   1   0
```